# Getting only last values from database in android

Tags: android, listview, android-database

I have stored values in database and now I am trying to get values from database. all values are stored in data base but when I get values in String list it only return the last values .following is my code .any help will be appreciated. please

public List GetBigRun() {

```
List<Run_Data_Model> bigRun_list = new ArrayList<>();

this.open();
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_BIG_RUN,
        allColumns_table_big_run, null,
        null, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Run_Data_Model mBigRunObj = new Run_Data_Model();
    mBigRunObj.RunBtnState = cursor.getString(1);
    mBigRunObj.RunImages = cursor.getString(2);
    mBigRunObj.RunColor = cursor.getString(3);
    mBigRunObj.RunDays = cursor.getString(4);
    mBigRunObj.RunTime = cursor.getString(5);
    bigRun_list.add(mBigRunObj);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
// Make sure to close the cursor
cursor.close();
this.close();
return bigRun_list;
```

}

here is database i created.

```
     public static final String TABLE_NAME_BIG_RUN ="big_run";

public static final String BIG_RUN_COLUMN_ID = "_id";

public static String BIG_RUN_BTN_STATE ="btn_state";
public static String BIG_RUN_BTN_IMAGE ="btn_image";
public static String BIG_RUN_BTN_COLOR ="btn_color";
public static String BIG_RUN_DAYS ="days";
public static String BIG_RUN_TIME ="time";


//Query for create table
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_BIG_RUN = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME_BIG_RUN + "("+ BIG_RUN_COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement,  " + BIG_RUN_BTN_STATE
        + " text ,  " + BIG_RUN_BTN_IMAGE
        + " text ,  " + BIG_RUN_BTN_COLOR
        + " text ,  " + BIG_RUN_DAYS
        + " text ,  " + BIG_RUN_TIME
        +  " text );";
```

here i am saving values in database.

```
     private void PutValues() {
   mydata.DeleteAllBigRun();
    /*if(mPref.GetRunCount().equals("0")) {*/

        for (int i = 0; i < 73; i++) {
            Run_Data_Model runModel = new Run_Data_Model();
            runModel.RunDays = "Day " + (i + 12);
            runModel.RunImages = String.valueOf(R.drawable.cross_icon);
            runModel.RunBtnState = "0";
            runModel.RunColor = "#e76025";


       /* if (id == 1) {*/
            sec = sec + 20;
            int mins = sec / 60;
            int remainder = sec - mins * 60;
            int secs = remainder;
            runModel.RunTime = mins + " min " + secs + " sec";


       /* } else if (id == 2) {
            sec = sec + 40;
            int mins = sec / 60;
            int remainder = sec - mins * 60;
            int secs = remainder;
            runModel.RunTime = mins + " min " + secs + " sec";
            runModel.RunChallengeState = "2";

        } else if (id == 3) {
            runModel.RunTime = (i + 1) + " min ";
            runModel.RunChallengeState = "3";
        }*/
            mydata.InsertBigRunInTable(runModel.RunBtnState, runModel.RunImages, runModel.RunColor, runModel.RunDays, runModel.RunTime);

        }
        mPref.SetRunCount("1");
    //}


}
```

and this is how i am getting the values in list and passing it to adapter.

```
       run_list = mydata.GetBigRun();
   /* for(int i=0;i<run_list.size();i++) {
        Log.d("run_list_size", run_list.get(i).RunDays);
    }*/
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gv.setNumColumns(4);
    RunChallengeAdapter adapter =new RunChallengeAdapter(this,run_list);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
Every thing in my code is correct and working, the only mistake I was making was my model objects. I unintentionally added static with objects which was creating problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

    Run_Data_Model mBigRunObj = new Run_Data_Model();
    mBigRunObj.RunBtnState = cursor.getString(1);
    mBigRunObj.RunImages = cursor.getString(2);
    mBigRunObj.RunColor = cursor.getString(3);
    mBigRunObj.RunDays = cursor.getString(4);
    mBigRunObj.RunTime = cursor.getString(5);
    bigRun_list.add(mBigRunObj);

    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

use above code and check

Comment: Still no luck returning the same last value only.

Comment: i will surely accept the answer but its not useful for me . :(

Comment: have you removed cursor.moveToFirst(); above while from your code

Comment: yes i remove that line

Comment: should i send u any other part of code?

Comment: cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(pass your column names)) for each